# Why does my code skip input prompts after the second one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking at it a while and any help is infinitely appreciated.

```
secret = "Meow"
guess = ""
limit = 1

while guess != secret and limit <= 5:
    if limit == 2:
        print("You have 4 guesses left!")
    elif limit == 3:
        print("You have 3 guesses left!")
    elif limit == 4:
        print("You have 2 guesses left!")
    elif limit == 5:
        print("You have 1 guess left!")

    if limit == 1:
        guess = input("What's the secret? OwO You have 5 guesses. ")
    elif limit <= 2:
        guess = input("What's the secret? OwO. ")

    limit += 1

print("You cheated! Or lost.")
```

When run, it does it's usually input attempt and after getting the question wrong once it says 5 attempts left and asks the input again, but after that it skips the input prompt and only says guesses left. Output with guesses:

```
What's the secret? OwO You have 5 guesses. idk man  
You have 4 guesses left!  
What's the secret? OwO. 2nd try?  
You have 3 guesses left!  
You have 2 guesses left!  
You have 1 guess left!  
You cheated! Or lost.
```

Comment: If limit is > 2 neither of the conditions in the second if-elif-block are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a improvement to your code

```
secret = "Meow"
guess = ""
limit = 1

while guess != secret and limit <= 5:

    if limit == 1:
        guess = input("What's the secret? OwO You have 5 guesses. ")
    elif limit >= 2: #here was your mistake
        print("You have {0} guess left!".format(5-limit+1))
        guess = input("What's the secret? OwO. ")

    limit += 1

print("You cheated! Or lost.")
```

Comment: @Kayo i think you want something like this val=5-limit+1. print(f"You have {val} guess left!")

Comment: I actually messed around with it a bit and realized I could just replace the 0 in the brackets with 5 - limit + 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

just make this changed :

`elif limit >= 2:`

```py
secret = "Meow"
guess = ""
limit = 1

while guess != secret and limit <= 5:
    if limit == 2:
        print("You have 4 guesses left!")
    elif limit == 3:
        print("You have 3 guesses left!")
    elif limit == 4:
        print("You have 2 guesses left!")
    elif limit == 5:
        print("You have 1 guess left!")

    if limit == 1:
        guess = input("What's the secret? OwO You have 5 guesses. ")
    elif limit >= 2:
        guess = input("What's the secret? OwO. ")

    limit += 1

print("You cheated! Or lost.")
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I figured it'd be something silly, I just couldn't find it

Comment: ok. If you feel this help you don't forget to upvote and accept answer you have enough reputation,